# QGridLayout with colspan and rowspan

Tags: qt5, qtableview, qgridlayout

I can't create a QGridLayout like this one.

[image]

I tried but I failed

```
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
layout->addWidget(mytableview,0,0,1,3);
layout->addWidget(b1,1,0,1,1,Qt::AlignRight);
layout->addWidget(b2,1,1,1,1,Qt::AlignRight);
layout->addWidget(b3,1,2,1,1);
mainWindow->setLayout(layout);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this by using just `QGridLayout`. For the bottom area you need to use a `QHBoxLayout` and to use [QHBoxLayout::addStretch](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#addStretch) to add the spacing.

Here is an example:

*widget.h*:

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class QGridLayout;
class QHBoxLayout;
class QSpacerItem;
class QPushButton;
class QSpacerItem;
class QPushButton;
class QPushButton;
class QTableView;

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private:
    QGridLayout *gridLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout;
    QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacerLeft;
    QPushButton *pushButtonB1;
    QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacerRight;
    QPushButton *pushButtonB2;
    QPushButton *pushButtonB3;
    QTableView *tableView;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

*widget.cpp*:

```
#include "widget.h"

#include<QGridLayout>
#include<QHBoxLayout>
#include<QSpacerItem>
#include<QPushButton>
#include<QSpacerItem>
#include<QPushButton>
#include<QPushButton>
#include<QTableView>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    gridLayout = new QGridLayout(this);
    horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout();

    horizontalLayout->addStretch(3);

    pushButtonB1 = new QPushButton(this);
    pushButtonB1->setText("B1");

    horizontalLayout->addWidget(pushButtonB1);

    horizontalLayout->addStretch(1);

    pushButtonB2 = new QPushButton(this);
    pushButtonB2->setText("B2");

    horizontalLayout->addWidget(pushButtonB2);

    pushButtonB3 = new QPushButton(this);
    pushButtonB3->setText("B3");

    horizontalLayout->addWidget(pushButtonB3);

    gridLayout->addLayout(horizontalLayout, 1, 0, 1, 1);

    tableView = new QTableView(this);

    gridLayout->addWidget(tableView, 0, 0, 1, 1);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
}
```

*main.cpp*:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Result:

[image]